# Cross product of each row of a matrix by another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

```
Suppose I have a matrix
```

A       =

```
      [1, 2, 3;
       4, 5, 6;
       7, 8, 9;
       8, 7, 6];
```

I want the cross product of each row of A and another matrix B, where

B       =

```
      [1, 0.5, 0.5;
       0.5, 1, 0.5;
       0.5, 0.5, 1];
```

A for loop could be written as,

```
for(i in 1:4)
{
      t(A[i,])%*%B;
}
```

Is there a more optimized way of doing this without using the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three below solutions are equivalent and provide the same results; however they are different in the performance. I did run them in a loop of `10000` iterations to compare their average performance and here is the result:

1-

```
for(i in 1:4)
{
  t(A[i,])%*%B;
}
```

**Time:  0.46**

2-

```
apply(A,1,crossprod,B)
```

**Time:  0.58**

3-

```
t(A %*% B)
```

or

```
t(tcrossprod(A,B))
```

**Time:  0.08**

Answer (score 1):

Not really more optimized but it looks better ,

```
apply(A,1,crossprod,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

R has a built in function for this:

```
    A %*% B
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
    # [1,]  3.5    4  4.5
    # [2,]  9.5   10 10.5
    # [3,] 15.5   16 16.5
    # [4,] 14.5   14 13.5
```